# Cannot Change Size of Images using include_graphics in R markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

Image size won't get larger in r-markdown knitr pdf rendering

````
\newpage
\blandscape

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align="center", warning=FALSE, dpi=NA, fig.height=20, fig.width=20}
knitr::include_graphics(list_B)

```
\elandscape
````

I have tried to use `out.width`, `fig.width`, and getting rid of the aspect ratio but my image size doesn't change. I can make it smaller, but it won't go larger. The file `list_B` is a list of file paths.

Comment: I have also tried changing margins but the image goes off the page

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the size of displayed figures by setting the chunk options  `out.width`/`out.height`. You can set only one of these two options if you want to keep the aspect ratio of the figures.

`fig.width` and `fig.height` affect the physical size of plots that are created using graphical functions such as `ggplot()`, and these options will not change the display size.

See [5.4 Control the size of plots/images](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html) of *R Markdown Cookbook* by Xie et al for more details.

````
\newpage
\blandscape

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align="center", warning=FALSE, dpi=NA, fig.height=20, fig.width=20, out.width="120%"}
knitr::include_graphics(list_B)
```

\elandscape
````

Comment: Appreciate the reply, but I did try out.width as I mentioned above. It works to minimize but not enlarge. So I am assuming it is something with page container or margins, but can't figure it out